# VS2017 doesn't deploy Android APK ("Deploy target provider not found for debugger 'AndroidEmulator'.")

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-cordova

I try to create a development enviroment for Cordova/Ionic with Visual Studio 2017 to build an app for Android and iOS. Finally I managed that VS builds the APK file succesfully  but it doesn't get deployed.

I receive the following error:

> Deploy target provider not found for debugger 'AndroidEmulator'.

I selected "Simulate in Browser - Nexus 6" as target.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: What are you trying to run it on? Ms emulator/Google emulator/real device?

Comment: No, VS says the target is "Simulate in Browser - Nexus 6". (I added this info to my question)

Comment: Personally I had to manually start "Visual Studio Emulator for Android" and start up a device. Then I had to run VS2017 as Administrator, and select "Device" from the dropdown menu

Comment: "Simulate in browser" is almost the same as opening your index.html in Firefox. You should deploy to real emulators (or devices) instead, then connect to the debugger using Chrome's device inspector.